# forzar proyecto con angular 7 e ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic, angular7, ionic4

Por necesidades de un proyecto, tenemos que usar la versión de Angular 7 y la versión de Ionic 4. 
Con la instalación global de Angular/CLI 7 (`npm install -g @angular/cli@7`), crea un proyecto de Angular 7 sin ningún problema.

Sin embargo al crear el proyecto con Ionic (aunque instale el CLI 4 de Ionic) crea el proyecto utilizando Ionic 5 y Angular 8 (las últimas estables actualmente). Puedo bajar la versión de Ionic modificando el package.json, pero cuando intento modificar la versión de Angular (a la "~7.2.0" por ejemplo), después de borrar el `package-lock.json`, la carpeta `node_modules` y su respectivo `npm install`, me da bastantes errores de dependencias, que aunque puedo ir solucionando de a poco, no termina de quedar fino del todo.

Mi preguntas es, a la hora de hacer un "ionic start" ¿hay alguna manera de forzar a que cree el proyecto con una versión concreta de Ionic y Angular?

Desde ya muchas gracias por todo,
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero proba instalar la versión de ionic que querés:

`npm i -g ionic@4.0.0-rc.13`,

luego en la consola de comandos dale `ionic info`, para ver si se instaló la versión deseada, por ultimo dale `ionic start` y luego de crear el proyecto podes bajar la versión de angular a la que quieras con:

`npm i @angular/cli@7.0.1`

esto va a actualizar solo el `package.json`. Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola Tomas, muchas gracias por contestar. He seguido los pasos que me has dicho (muy parecidos a los que ya había intentando, salvo por la última parte que la hacía manual).

Comment: y funcionó? por casualidad estas haciendo un "npm install"

Comment: envié sin querer y no me deja editar:

Comment: Hola Tomas, muchas gracias por contestar. He seguido los pasos que me has dicho (muy parecidos a los que ya había intentando, salvo por la última parte que la hacía manual).
Al volver a instalar Ionic y hacer un `ionic info` me aparece la versión 4.0.0-rc.13 del CLI efectivamente, pero al realizar el `ionic start` me genera el proyecto con la versión 5.0.4.
El último npm para angular me instala la versión del CLI en el proyecto local, pero no cambia la versión del framework de Angular.
De todas formas, muchas gracias, si consigo algo lo pondré por si a alguien le sirve,
Saludos!

Comment: bueno lo ultimo que se me ocurre es que generes el proyecto con ionic start, luego de eso anda a la carpeta del proyecto y usa 
"npm i ionic@4.0.0-rc.13 --save" , luego "npm i @angular/cli@7.0.1 --save" y proba ionic info.

Comment: Gracias por seguir el caso @Tomas. Nada, ya he probado y tiene pinta de que lo único que cambia de versión sería el CLI (como tenia la misma versión no ha hecho ningún cambio), la versión de los framework siguen siendo los mismos (Ionic 5.0.4 y Angular 8.3.25).